# Using a variable to define a logged in user

Tags: php

so I am trying to figure out a way to define a logged in user so that I can have it entered into a Db column when a user clicks on a button. The current problem is that when the user clicks the button, it is displaying the user of the person who is having the button clicked on them, instead of the person who actually clicked the button. Thanks for any help

So right now, test is the button and when the user clicks the button 7 times, it will put the user who has the button clicked on them in the DB under the row test2. So instead of that, I am trying to get the person who clicks the button to be put into that row instead.

```
if ($test==7) {

                try {

                    $st = $DB->prepare('
                        UPDATE users 
                        SET test2 = username
                        WHERE username LIKE :username
                    ');

                    $st->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $username
                    ));
                    } catch (Exception $e) {

                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
```

Comment: its not very clear, please clarify

Comment: Will the person who clicks the button be logged in?

Comment: @DoctorDerp no, the user has to already be logged in to click the button

Comment: Ehm.. i don't understand what is the problem. A user click the button but another user sees the change instead of the user who clicked?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno it's not really a change, all I am trying to do is have the user who clicks on the button have their username put into the db row instead of the person who has the button next to them.

Answer (score 0):

So he will be logged in?, if so, when the user logs in, pass his user_id to the $_SESSION, then when the user clicks the button, get the user_id from the $_SESSION.